# OpenCV compiled for WinRT ARM missing highgui and videoio

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to compile opencv for WinRT WS (windows store) ARM architecture and all is good, i'm able to compile and build it all, getting the libraries and all that, but its missing the highgui and videoio headers and libraries. Is there are reason for this? i'm compiling the latest opencv code

opencv_contrib300.lib is also missing (debug and release) along with the videoio and highgui libs

EDIT:
So because i'm compiling for winrt, some of the features are taken out (contrib isn't even part of the latest branch anymore, so thats why i wasn't able to see that)

Basically, what i'm missing from the build which i was hoping to have, was VideoCapture and less importantly, imshow, which are both from the highgui module.

Is there another option for grabbing images from a camera other than VideoCapture that i'd be able to use for winrt?

Comment: don't know about highgui and videoio (rt might differ from the usual here), but opencv_contrib.lib does not exist *at all* in opencv3.0 (removed / moved to a separate github repo)

Comment: also see: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/4005 (in general, keep a close eye on the github activity)

Comment: did you select highgui and videoio before compiling opencv? how did you configure opencv before compiling/installing?

Comment: alright, i'm looking through the cmakelists.txt right now. i see that there are things taken out for winrt, so thats why i'm not seeing them. I didn't do any configuration, just running the powershell script for winrt. i've taken out the windows phone parameters and x86 parameters

Comment: i guess now that i see some things are added/removed because of compiling for winrt, my original question has to change to what are the alternatives to some of these features, if anything in opencv.